# Passing Params to a Window[callback] Function

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, window

I have some code that requests some JSON from an API. When data is returned, per the documentation, it sends back a callback function that is to be used to parse the data at the top level. After the call is made, I have the following code to capture the data and process it:

```
var callback = 'functionUsedInApiCall';
window[callback] = newCallBackFunction;
```

How would I go about passing custom params to the callback function above as the data is being returned?

In order to capture the data, I must write the callback function like this:

```
function newCallBackFunction(root) {
   //root is the data
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)? If so, *you* don't call the callback or pass in the argument at all, the code returned by the API does.

E.g., your code:

```
window.myCallback = newCallbackFunction;

function newCallbackFunction(data) {
    // use the data
}
```

(I'm assuming this isn't at global scope, hence assigning to the `window` object.)

...plus your code for initiating the JSONP call, which is usually appending a `script` element to your page with a URL containing the name of the callback ("myCallback" in the above).

Their response will look like this:

```
myCallback({
    // data here
});
```

...which, when it arrives, will run (because it's the content of a `script` element), and will call your function. This is how JSONP works.

---

If you want to include *further* arguments for the function, all you do is have the callback they call turn around and call your target function, e.g.:

```
window.myCallback = function(data) {
    newCallbackFunction(data, "foo", "bar");
};

function newCallbackFunction(data) {
    // use the data
}
```

Now when their code calls the global `myCallback`, all it does is turn around and call `newCallbackFunction` with that data *and* the arguments you specify.

Those arguments don't have to be literals as in the above. Here's an example with a bit more context, using a [closure](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html):

```
// Assume the url already contains the name of the callback "myCallback"
function doJSONP(url, niftyInfo, moreNiftyInfo) {
     var script;

     // Set up the callback
     window.myCallback = function(data) {
        // Runs when the data arrives
        newCallbackFunction(data, niftyInfo, moreNiftyInfo);
     };

     // Trigger the request
     script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = url;
     document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

Ideally, though, when doing JSONP you auto-generate the name of the callback each time so that it's specific to the request (in case you have two outstanding requests at the same time):

```
// Assume the url ends with "callback=" and we append the name of the
// callback function to it
function doJSONP(url, niftyInfo, moreNiftyInfo) {
     var cbname, script;

     // Get a callback name
     cbname = "callback_" +
              new Date().getTime() +
              "_" +
              Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

     // Set up the callback
     window[cbname] = function(data) {
        // Remove us from the window object
        try {
            delete window[cbname];
        }
        catch (e) { // Handle IE bug (throws an error when you try to delete window properties)
            window[cbname] = undefined;
        }

        // Runs the function
        newCallbackFunction(data, niftyInfo, moreNiftyInfo);
     };

     // Trigger the request
     script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = url + encodeURIComponent(cbname);
     document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! And yes, I am auto-generating for each specific call, just wasn't sure how to pass other data into the callback when it is fired. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Parameters in javascript are passed as an Array, so you can pass the parameters you need, or even complete functions that will add per case functionality in your callback.

You could do the following:

```
function newCallBackFunction(root /*your data*/, paramsHash /*a hash array with optional parameters*/)
{
   //if arg1 can be found in the hash
   if( paramsHash['arg1'] ] 
   {
      //do something that requires arg1
   }
   else if( paramsHash['arg2'] )
   {
      //do something that requires arg2 
   }


   return root;

}
```

And in your main code:

```
var hash = new Array(); 
hash['arg1'] = 'str1';
hash['arg2'] = 1;
hash['arg3'] = new Car(); //or any other object you want
```

It is also possible to just declare some parameters and supply them to your function only when needed:

```
function newCallBackFunction(root, param1, param2)
{
   if( param1 ) { /* similar to first example */ }
}
```

Or finally just pass whatever parameter you want and read them from the arguments table

```
function newCallBackFunction(root)
{
   for( int i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ )
     //do something with the parameters you pass beside root
}
```

And in main code:

```
 newCallBackFunction( root, param1, param2, param3 );
```

I hope I covered you!

Comment: *"Parameters in javascript are passed as an Array"* No, they aren't. The underlying mechanism for passing arguments around is implementation-dependent, but they end up being properties of the *binding object* of the *variable environment* generated for the call to the function (see Sections [10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) and 10.5 of the spec). The `arguments` object is not an array (although it has some array-like behavior), and in most implementations it's only created if you use it in the function (and at a runtime cost, on some engines a significant one).